# Equation to manage non weighted flow

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, equation, max-flow

I have a graph like the one below.

[image]

This represents nodes linked by path. One node stands for the start (on the left) and the other for the end (on the right).

My goal is to send troops from the start to the end following some rules :

- Nodes can contain only one unit (except for the start and the end that are not limited)
- Unit can only advance one node per turn
- Once an unit has advanced on a node different than start, it has to move at every turn, there cannot be congestion.

I'm trying to find an equation that calculate the minimal number of turns to achieve that goal depending on the number of troops I need to send. It would also helps me to know how many path I should use to optimize the flow of my troops.

For example, in my graph it would take 3 turns to send 2 units, I would only use the path on the top.

But for 15 units, it would be more optimized to send some units in the path in the middle and maybe the one on the bottom of my graph too.

I have an hard time finding a equation to manage my flow.

I hope you understood my problem and thanks for reading !

Comment: Are you asking for an *equation* or an *algorithm or code*? If the former, this is the wrong site for this question. This site is about practical computer programming. The equation request is also not clear: an equation for what, exactly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the request for an equation show that it is not about practical computer programming.

Comment: Ok, Is computer science a good site to post algorithm problem on ?

Comment: In general, yes, but check their standards for questions on their site. I'm sure you will need to clarify just what you are asking for.

Comment: I think this question if perfectly fine for SO, although it needs some clarification. After all, the equation is most likely represented in the form of an algorithm. @galemair: Do the paths always share only start and end or can they also intersect?

Comment: Hi, indeed, in some graphs there can be intersection and I forgot an important rule in my question, I just modified it. My algorithm so far is able to find the differents paths that doesn't intersect. I just need now to find an equation that allows me to choose which combination of paths is the most optimized

Comment: So, should an answer assume that we have disjoint paths or should it also optimize that part?

Comment: The answer should assume that the paths are disjoint indeed. Like in the example, there wont be any path cutting the way of other paths

Answer (score 0):

For each of the paths, count how many nodes are on them (excluding start and target). Then, a path with `k` nodes will start providing one unit per turn after `k` turns. Then, sort your paths by `k` and do a turn-wise simulation. Maintain the current number of units at the target and the current unit rate (number of paths with `k <= currentTime`). Then, increase the current unit number by the unit rate until you reach the desired target number.

In essence, your unit rate is a piecewise constant function (over time). Therefore, the number of units is a constant linear function (over time). But I guess, representing this as a function is not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reasonable approximation by solving a node-capacitated max flow problem, decomposing the flow into unit paths, and then sending a stream of units along each path. The throughput will be optimal, but long paths may incur extra delay.